# How do I scan my bitcoin receipt into my wallet?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I bought Bitcoins from the Robocoin ATM (I'm told it's the only one) and it gave me a receipt with a QR code to scan into my wallet. I downloaded Blockchain, but don't see where in the app I can scan the receipt to add to my wallet. Help!

Comment: What does "I downloaded blockchain" mean? What program are you using exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Using the blockchain.info app go to your address book (menu button in top left).. then when in the address book click the same top-left menu button and you'll see the import private key option. Scan the QR, job done.

Alternatively use a QR scanning app such as QRDroid and then you can copy & paste the resulting private key into anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

Find a button labeled "import private key", and it'll open a camera view to let you scan the QR code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm not seeing that button. There are 4 tabs on the bottom. On the piggyback one the screen just says "No Data". Refreshing does nothing.